# Syntax error when using decorator and running code selection in terminal (macOS)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I select and run Selection with the below code:

```
@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    surname: str
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> @dataclass
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: can you tell which OS you are using, Windows, linux based, MacOS ?

Comment: I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15058) in how VS Code handles running decorators using "Run Selection".

There's not much you can do other than wait until there's a new update fixing it.